# Cannot edit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/mdadm and /etc/udev/rules.d/RULE on 16.04 Server

Tags: networking, server, raid, udev, mdadm

I have just installed Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS with a RAID 1 configuration.

I want to edit the `mdadm` file so I could work on the machine while the raid mode is degraded. The problem is, that there is no `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/mdadm` file. I've entered `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdadm` but did not succeed.

Another issue I have experienced is changing the names of the ip links. 
There is nothing in `/etc/udev/rules.d/RULE` so I cannot edit it.

If I change them using `ip link set ...` I lose the changes after restart.

What are the alternatives to set my RAID properly and edit the names of the ip links without editing the `rc.local` file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The idea, to me, is that you create them if they are not there.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.
I am taking in mind your advice for future asks.
I just thought that my two problems are from the same nature. 
But I get the idea and I think you are right.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello again Ubuntu users.

My networking problem is solved by creating a 70-persistent-net.rules file in `/etc/udev/conf.d/`.

I still experience the problem with the software raid1.
When I remove one of the disks it does not work out.
What I have done is to add `BOOT_DEGRADED=true` in `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`.

Comment: Please, consider to accept this answer. You can accept also your own answers. It is completely normal work process to solve own problems/challenges.